# JSCS How to disable for a specific part of code rule requireDotNotation?

Tags: jscs

I am using JSCS to validate my code and I have [requireDotNotation](http://jscs.info/rule/requireDotNotation) set to on for all my code base, but for a **specific part of code** I need to disable this rule.

Basically I would need to do something similar (example working for JSHint) but for JSCS:

```
/*jshint sub:true*/
//some code here
/*jshint sub:false*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue using the following code:

```
//jscs:disable requireDotNotation
//some code here
//jscs:enable requireDotNotation
```

I am adding this answer hope can help others.